# If text string exist select cell containing text string

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, vba

I recorded a macro that finds a text string and then it deletes. My problem is that sometimes that text string does not exist. I would appreciate some help in changing the macro to check if the text string exist and then select it. Below is what I currently have. Thanks in advance.

```
Cells.Find(What:="Test" _
, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) _
.Activate
Selection.ClearContents
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Range.Find` returns `Nothing` when the search term cannot be found, so this should work:

```
Set found = Cells.Find(What:="Test" _
, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not found Is Nothing Then
    found.Activate
    found.ClearContents
End If
```

You can leave out `found.Activate` if you don't want to move the cursor to where the string is found.